# Iterating through strings in list and concatenating to string before it if string meets conditions

Tags: python

I have a list composed of many strings that have been split at `'\n'`. However, in the raw text file itself, there are a few newlines inserted in the middle of an entry, which makes things confusing.

**I want to iterate through the list and ask if the first character is equal to `'r'` or `'i'`. If not, I want to concatenate that string with the one before it.**

This is an excerpt of what my current list looks like:

```
[‘rs386834028,46662406,1,No summary provided.,http://www.snpedia.com/index.php/Rs386834028(CA;CA)', 'rs121909207,94480221,1,"common in clinvar', '",http://www.snpedia.com/index.php/Rs121909207(C;C)']
```

The first element in the list is what I want all elements of the list to look like. I want the second and the third to be concatenated together to look as such:

```
[‘rs386834028,46662406,1,No summary provided.,http://www.snpedia.com/index.php/Rs386834028(CA;CA)', 'rs121909207,94480221,1,"common in clinvar,http://www.snpedia.com/index.php/Rs121909207(C;C)']
```

This is what my code looks like right now:

```
import io
def readSNP(filename1):
    f = io.open(filename1, mode='r', encoding='utf8')
    fileAsOneString = f.read()
    splitList = fileAsOneString.split('\n')
    for string in splitList:
        for i in range(len(string)):
            if (i[0] =! 'r' or i[0] =! 'i'):
```

And that's where I get stuck. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: It would help if you could turn this into a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Something that's runnable, including sample input, and the desired vs. expected output.

Comment: Yes, we need the MCVE.  Among other deficiencies, the "list" you posted is not a valid Python list.  Most of all, you have *no* strings in the list, just characterse that are invalid at that point in the scanning.

Comment: It's a pity you've put all this effort into a decent question that is only lacking a reproducible example with some actual copy-pastable data. Please fix that and your question will be a lot more amenable.

Comment: @abarnert: A cut&paste response is easy, and the full phrase helps OP understand sooner what's required.

Comment: @timgeb Thanks. I remembered them rejecting the proposal to add shortcut links like that, and never checked that they'd changed their minds somewhere in the intervening years because I'm an idiot. :) Much easier.

Comment: @abarnert haha, I did not even know about the proposal and found that shortcut by accident. :)

Comment: Yep @abarnert. There's also one for a link to the help center -> `[help]`. Not sure if there are any others though.

Comment: @ChristianDean There are more: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Great! thanks @JohnnyMopp. I didn't know about that page.

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate through the list and `pop()` and concatenate non-matching values to the previous item.

```
i = 0
while i < len(lst):
    if not (lst[i].startswith('i') or list[i].startswith('r')):
        lst[i - 1] += lst.pop(i)
    else:
        i += 1
```

Comment: Not a bad solution, but concatenating strings in a loop is not exactly a good idea (because it's slow). A more efficient solution would use `''.join`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey  That might be true if I was concatenating *many* strings at once, but it this case it appears the OP only ever wants to concatenate two strings together, and in that case, `'str' + 'str'` isn't any slower than `.join()`